# React Native Component - OnPress Function not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

My question is about adding buttons with `onPress` events in imported components.

So I've built an external button component which I'm importing into `app.js` from a `component.js` file

```
export default class App extends Component {

  {...}

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(245, 247, 250)' }}>
        {renderIf(display.beacon, <Beacon />)}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This `<Beacon />` component displays an image and two buttons imported from another component file:

```
export class Beacon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
        <Image
          source={require("./scenerios/Welcome.png")}
          style={styles.MainContainer}
          />
          </Row>
          <Row style={ {backgroundColor: Blue} } >
          <ButtonWhite onPress={this._startScanning} name={"Start Scanning"} />
          <ButtonWhite onPress={this._stopScanning} name={"Stop Scanning"} />
          </Row>  
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

When I use these `<ButtonWhite />` components in the app render like below they work fine:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  {...}

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(245, 247, 250)' }}>
          <ButtonWhite onPress={this._startScanning} name={"Start Scanning"} />
          <ButtonWhite onPress={this._stopScanning} name={"Stop Scanning"} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

The moment I move these to the component, they display on screen but do not call the function.

Comment: you should check the callbacks you are passing as props

Comment: These work fine when I use the buttons in the app render though, wondering if I might need to reference the functions in the component?

Comment: yes you must have somehow a reference to the function you are passing as props

Comment: That's exactly what I can't figure out, any ideas on how that might be done?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the place where you render the component:

```
{renderIf(display.beacon, <Beacon />)}
```

Then you want to pass props to the component:

```
{renderIf(display.beacon, <Beacon
  startScanning={() => this._startScanning()}
  stopScanning ={() => this._stopScanning()}
/>)}
```

And in `Beacon` component you want to call the props:

```
export class Beacon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
        <Image
          source={require("./scenerios/Welcome.png")}
          style={styles.MainContainer}
         />
         </Row>
         <Row style={ {backgroundColor: Blue} } >
         <ButtonWhite onPress={this.props.startScanning} name={"Start Scanning"} />
         <ButtonWhite onPress={this.props.stopScanning} name={"Stop Scanning"} />
         </Row>  
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. I know the previous way wasn't ideal but it worked. Thank you for clearing that up 

Comment: I am glad I could help. Note that I also used arrow function `() => this._startScanning()` because I want to use the `_startScanning` in a correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

avoid to call

```
 this._stopScanning
```

once you are moving your component you need to import the callback from your component

```
import {_stopScanning} from <Component where you have the callbacks>
```

otherwise you need to refactor the component and just call the function internally instad to receive them as props

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Needed to use constructor to reference the function.

```
export class UnknownBeacon extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
      {
        mainAppRef : props.mainAppRef
      };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
        <Image
          source={require("./scenerios/Welcome.png")}
          style={styles.MainContainer}
         />
         </Row>
         <Row style={ {backgroundColor: tflBlue} } >
         <TfLButtonWhite onPress={this.state.mainAppRef._startScanning} name={"Start Scanning"} />
         <TfLButtonWhite onPress={this.state.mainAppRef._stopScanning} name={"Stop Scanning"} />
         </Row>  
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is a REALLY BAD way how to handle callbacks in react.